# Is there a tool for generating historical process oriented resource usage statistics like top output?

Tags: system-information, statistics

I've seen many tools like collectd, systats etc for recording general usage statistics, but I would like to find a tool for generating a historical graph of system resource consumption of the top 10 processes running in a system at sample intervals.

Think of like running top and taking the top 10 processes and saving to and RRD database to see what programs are putting a certain system under load over time.

Perhaps it's just a matter of configuration of something like systats, so perhaps there are some examples online of this.

Comment: take a look at --
http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html